# Visual Studio comment shortcut not working for OpenCL (*.cl) files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencl, keyboard-shortcuts

I installed the Intel OpenCL SDK and everything seems to work fine, including syntax highlighting for *.cl-Files in Visual Studio. However: I cannot use the keyboard shortcut for commenting out code (works fine in C++-files). Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to settings Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extensions, pick Microsoft Visual C++ editor and add `cl` file extension.